# Can't store output of a function in a vector

Tags: r, excel

new to R programming so I'm having a little trouble here.

Piece of code:

```
cca_rank<-function(x){for(x in 1:nrow(adm)) {
  if(adm$cca[x]<=400){print("Low")} else if(adm$cca[x]>400 & adm$cca[x]<=700){print("Mid")} else if(adm$cca[x]>700){print("High")}}}
cca_ranks <- cca_rank(1:400)
```

adm is a excel sheet with a table of 400 rows. cca_rank(1:400) returns the correct output for me, but I'm able to put all the Lows, Mediums, and Highs into a single vector. I need to place this vector in a data frame. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: your function is not returning anything, just printing

Comment: This is what `?cut` is made for

Comment: Is there any way I can get it to return Low, Mid, and High instead of printing out the results? I need to combine these results into the adm dataframe.

Comment: see docendo comment and try `cut` (your function has other problems by the way, you take x as function parameter but then you define x as the index in the loop...)

Comment: Ah, I have never learned the cut function before so please pardon me for asking, if i create the vector cca_ranks<-adm$cca, for the cut function do i do it like cut(cca_ranks,c(0.5,400.5,700.5,800.5),labels=c("Low","Medium",‌​"High")) ?

Comment: `cut(cca_ranks, breaks=c(0, 400, 700, 800), labels=c("Low", "Medium", "High"))`

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is working now. You all are awesome :)